# Invalid syntax error when using print

Tags: python, printing

I get an error

```
invalid syntax
```

when I run the following code:

```
print("Hello how old are you?(years)"
print ("(1) 0-10")      
print ("(2) 11-20")
print ("(3) 21-30")
print ("(4) 31-40")
print ("(5) 41-50")
print ("(6) 51-60")
print ("(7) 61-70")
print ("(8) 71-80")
print ("(9) 81-90")
print ("(10)90+")
  c=input
  if int(c)==1
print ("")
```

On this line

```
print ("(1) 0-10")
```

it says print is a invalid syntax, if i delete that line it moves on to the next, and so on. Please could i have some help here? Thanks!

Comment: Missing `)` on this line: `print("Hello how old are you?(years)"`

Comment: Thank you very much. i didn't see that!!!

Answer (score 8):

```
print("Hello how old are you?(years)") # <== missing this )
```

You're next syntax errors will probably be the following:

```
c=input() # <== missing ()

if int(c)==1: # <== missing :
    print ("") # missing indentation
```

Just fyi whenever you get that kind of behaviour `if i delete that line it moves on to the next, and so on.` that probably means the syntax error is not on that line but the line before it.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer, i didn't realise it was the line before!

Comment: @Calzs34 please consider accepting this answer if it helps you meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235/235416